# What if stegasaurs continued to evolve?

Tags: evolution, alternate-reality, dinosaurs

I know it's unlikely due to ankylosaurs being so successful, but this is an avenue of speculative evolution not yet explored. So let's say that the KT extinction didn't occur and Cretaceous stegosaurs continued to evolve to modern day. What would they be like? Some examples of such dinosaurs would be wuerhosaurus, paranthodon, and craterosaurus. (Sorry if I mispelled. On a cellphone). It's thought wuerhosaurus is the result of Jurassic dinosaurs that survived in an isolated pocket in Russia, so this theory has a little more weight.

Comment: Their descendants would look very much like a [kangaroo mouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangaroo_mouse) covered with a soft spiny integument, shimmering in the desert light. They descendants would be semiaquatic fossorial animals, similar to [desmans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desman) but rather scaly and slithery. Their much simplified descendants would look like papery [caecilians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caecilian), burrowing into the soft topsoil hunting for earthworms. Their bat-like descendants would be the terror of Siberian nights, silently diving to prey on tiger cubs.

Comment: This seems open-ended and opinion-based. What's the criteria for deciding which answer is best?

Comment: Determining an evolution path that literally spans millions of years can only be pure speculation. A better question would be to give us an end result of the stegosaurus and ask whether its plausible such a creature could evolve from it.

Comment: The criteria is whichever is backed by the most convincing scientific argument.

Comment: AlexP, what are you talking about?

Comment: What I am talking about? Consider aardvarks, bats, camels, elephants, foxes, hedgehogs, horses, humans, manatees, moles, pangolins, pigs, rabbits, rats, sheep, squirrels, tigers, and whales: their most recent common ancestor lived *after* the extinction of stegosaurid dinosaurs. That is, all those forms evolved from an animal which is *more recent* than *Stegosaurus* and *Craterosaurus*.

Comment: You're saying it could be radically different in ways we could barely imagine? That's not really what I had in mind, It's too simple.